# Hibernate not insert re-attached collection? (bug?)

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

version: 3.6.0.final

I have the following situation:
An entity with a collection, containing value type objects, with cascading fully enabled.

1) I remove, the collection and store it to the db. Then load it to check that the collection indeed is removed.
2) I then add the removed collection and store the entity again. Then I load it again to check the result and notice that the collection is empty, which it shouldn't :(...
What am I doing wrong or is this a bug?
When I use a clean created collection in 2), that doesn't exists of Hibernate objects, it works fine.., that is: the collection is correctly stored in the db.

In code, my mapping:

```
<class name="com.sample.Declaration" table="decl">
<id name="id" column="id" type="string" length="40" access="property">
   <generator class="assigned" />
</id>
<set name="statusHistory" table="decl_sts_hist" lazy="false" cascade="all">
   <cache usage="read-write" />
   <key column="idDec" not-null="true" />
   <composite-element class="com.sample.DeclarationStatusDefault">
     <property name="remark" column="remark" type="string" length="254" />
     <property name="statusName" column="stsName" type="declarationStatusName" not-null="true" update="false" />
   </composite-element>
</set>
</class>
```

The code:

```
// 1): clear the status history
Declaration dec = Persister.findDeclarationById("id");
SortedSet<DeclarationStatus> history = dec.getStatusHistory();
dec.setStatusHistory(null);
dec.saveOrUpdate(); // will call saveOrUpdate on the current session.

Declaration dec = Persister.findDeclarationById("id");
assertNull(dec.getStatusHistory()); // OK

// 2) recover the status history
dec.setStatusHistory(history);
dec.saveOrUpdate(); // will call saveOrUpdate on the current session.

Declaration dec = Persister.findDeclarationById("id");
assertNotNull(dec.getStatusHistory()); // ERROR, is empty like before
```

If I create a new Set with a few entries and store it, it all works fine, but when I store the old history that contains Hibernate objects, like the PersistSet, it will NOT be stored in the db...
Stranggeee.... Is this expected behavior?... I more smell like a bug or I am missing something here...

If I debug the Hibernate code, the collection entries are never marked as updated/recreated in the method Collections.prepareCollectionForUpdate() because the loadedPersister and currentPersister are the same for some reason...

Anybody any idea?

Answer (score 2):

*I belive the last statment in your test should be assert **NOT** Null: `assertNotNull(dec.getStatusHistory()); // ERROR, is empty like before` Anyway:*

**You should use the `clear` method instead of removing the set.**

So use:

```
dec.getStatisHistory().clear();
...
assertTrue(dec.getStatusHistoryHistory.isEmpty());
```

instead of:

```
dec.setStatusHistory(null);
...
assertNull(dec.getStatusHistory());
```

In hibernate it is allways a bad idea to remove a hibernate mannaged collection.

*BTW in my opinion, it is even a more cleaner approach to have a empty set instead of null*

**Added**

What you could try if you realy need to remove the collection is to copy its content in a new collection before adding it.

```
dec.setStatusHistory(new HashSet(history));
```

Comment: Yep, it must be assetNotTrue, thanks....  Your statement is however incorrect, try it. The clear indeed is needed between a Parent Child relation whereby the child is an entity as well, but not when the child is a entity as well, just like his parent. In this case, Hibernate has full control and is able to signal the changes. Test it yourself and you will see it. Thanks